# PHP Apple iOS Push Notifications: Command2 : Binary Interface and Notification Format

Tags: php, ios, binary, format, apple-push-notifications

Nowadays, PHP and Apple/iOS Push Notifications with Command 2 has been becoming popular. However not sure, how to prepare the format for same, as per [Apple guideline here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW6), How to achieve below packet format:

[image: PHP iOS Push Notifications: Command2 : Binary Interface and Notification Format]

Also would like to know, how to receive `Format of error-response packet` as mentioned below:

[image: Format of error-response packet]

At present, I am using below simple format:

```
$msg = 
// new: Command "1"
chr(1)
// new: Identifier "1111"
. chr(1) . chr(1) . chr(1) . chr(1)
// new: Expiry "tomorrow"
. pack('N', time() + 86400)
// old 
. chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

with

```
fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096785/new-command-2-apple-push-notification-not-sending-multiple-alerts)

Comment: I'm also trouble shooting with command 2 but for command 8 check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134749/about-the-apple-enhanced-notification-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//command 2
$msgInner =
  chr(1)
. pack('n', 32)
. pack('H*', $deviceToken)

. chr(2)
. pack('n', strlen($payload))
. $payload

. chr(3)
. pack('n', 4)
. chr(1).chr(1).chr(1).chr(1)

. chr(4)
. pack('n', 4)
. pack('N', time() + 86400)

. chr(5)
. pack('n', 1)
. chr(10);

$msg=
chr(2)
. pack('N', strlen($msgInner))
. $msgInner;
```

and for command 8 use this function: (by Yudmt) at [About the apple Enhanced notification format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134749/about-the-apple-enhanced-notification-format)

```
function error_response($fp)
{
    $read = array($fp);
    $null = null;
    $changedStreams = stream_select($read, $null, $null, 0, 1000000);

    if ($changedStreams === false)
    {
        echo ("Error: Unabled to wait for a stream availability");
    }
    elseif ($changedStreams > 0)
    {
        $responseBinary = fread($fp, 6);
        if ($responseBinary !== false || strlen($responseBinary) == 6)
        {
            $response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $responseBinary);
            var_dump($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change the $msg=
chr(2)
. pack('n', strlen($msgInner))
. $msgInner; 

to

$msg= chr(2) . pack('N', strlen($msgInner)) . $msgInner;

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in building $msg you need

```
. pack('N', strlen($msgInner))
```

since Apple's documentation says the frame length should be 4 bytes

> "Frame length - 4 bytes - The size of the frame data"

and for `pack()` 'n' generates 16 bits, while 'N' generates 32 bits

> n - unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order)
>
> N - unsigned long (always 32 bit, big endian byte order)