# PHP Apple Push Notification :command 2 Binary Interface and Notification multi messages

Tags: php, ios, binary, apple-push-notifications, pack

related to the question [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092378/php-apple-ios-push-notifications-command2-binary-interface-and-notification-f) , i didn't figure out how to send multi messages at once.

[the Binary frame image from Apple ios](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Art/aps_binary_provider_3_2x.png)

what about series of items?

how do i create an item ? and than a frame data?

i tried

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      //command 2
    $msgInner =
      chr(1)
    . pack('n', 32)
    . pack('H*', $row['device_token'])

    . chr(2)
    . pack('n', strlen($payload))
    . $payload

    . chr(3)
    . pack('n', 4)
    . $row['id']

    . chr(4)
    . pack('n', 4)
    . pack('N', time() + 86400)

    . chr(5)
    . pack('n', 1)
    . chr(10);

    $framedata.=$msgInner; //to accumulate (probably wrong, and need binary packing)
 } 
   $msg=
    chr(2)
    . pack('N', strlen($framedata))
    . $framedata;
```

it send only to the last row in my sql result.

can you please give me the correct packet format in code.

Answer (score 0):

it's best to ask a question it's even better if you answer your own question , and maybe someone else will learn.
In order to send multi message in the new format you need to send the messages like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $msgInner =
                      chr(1)  
                    . pack('n', 32)
                    . pack('H*', $row['device_token'])

                    . chr(2)
                    . pack('n', strlen($payload))
                    . $payload

                    . chr(3)    //Notification identifier
                    . pack('n', 4)
                    . pack('N', $row['id']) 

                    . chr(4)   //Expiration date
                    . pack('n', 4)
                    . pack('N', time() + 86400)

                    . chr(5)    //Priority
                    . pack('n', 1)
                    . chr(10);

                    $Imsg=
                        chr(2) //command 2
                        . pack('N', strlen($msgInner))
                        . $msgInner;

                    $allmessages=$allmessages.$Imsg;
}
```